# Connect SQL Server using C++ without /CLR

Tags: c++, sql-server, database-connection, clr

I want to connect SQL Server with C++, but when i write some SqlConnection, SqlCommand and so on... it requires to change "No Common Language Runtime Support" to "Common Language Runtime Support(/clr)" from my project properties. Also it requirs to change "Enable Minimal Rebuild - Yes(/Gm)" to "No (/Gm)" and also some other stuffs to be changed. When i change i am not able to use "thread" in my C++ project and also debuger is not showing anything. It just shows me red arrow.

And i wonder if there is any solution to Connect my C++ project to SQL Server without any changes from property?

Comment: There are several methods you can use in a native `c++` application to connect to a SQL server that don't use CLR. ADO is one of them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/ado-code-examples-in-visual-c?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Could you give me some links which would be helpful?

Comment: There are many examples in the link. here is one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-and-close-methods-example-vc?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You may also be interested in this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1075/A-set-of-ADO-classes-version-2-20